# Oracle - Find nearest values and date difference

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two table:

```
table1

user  start         end            parameter
1     1 jan 2010    31 mar 2010    abc
1     1 apr 2010    30 jun 2010    abc
1     1 jan 2010    31 mar 2010    xyz
1     1 apr 2010    30 jun 2010    xyz
1     1 jan 2010    31 mar 2010    qqq
1     1 apr 2010    30 jun 2010    qqq

table2

start         end            parameter  value
1 jan 2009    31 mar 2009    abc        100
1 apr 2009    30 jun 2009    abc        200
1 jan 2009    31 mar 2009    xyz        300
1 apr 2009    30 jun 2009    xyz        400
1 jan 2009    31 mar 2009    qqq        500
1 apr 2009    30 jun 2009    qqq        600
```

I have to associate the 2 tables based on parameter, start and end. I need to find the nearest values. So, for ex. 1 jan 2010 - 31 mar 2010 for parameter abc, we don't have any values in table2, so get the nearest value, i.e.  1 apr 2009 - 30 jun 2009 with parameter abc and associate value 200. Also, find the difference of days from start of both tables.

The resulting table should look like:

table3:

```
user  start         end            parameter  value   diff
1     1 jan 2010    31 mar 2010    abc        200     270 days
1     1 apr 2010    30 jun 2010    abc        200     365 days
1     1 jan 2010    31 mar 2010    xyz        400     270 days
1     1 apr 2010    30 jun 2010    xyz        400     365 days
1     1 jan 2010    31 mar 2010    qqq        600     270 days
1     1 apr 2010    30 jun 2010    qqq        600     365 days
```

Comment: Is this data really in two different tables, rather than all in the same table?

Comment: How are you defining 'nearest' - the latest table2 that ends before the table1 end? Or would a future record be allowed if that started sooner than the old one ended - and what if they tied?

Comment: @Boneist - they are in different tables

Comment: @AlexPoole - if they tied, we just take the value and put diff as 0 days. The nearest mean comparing start of table1 with start of table2.

Comment: I meant if you have no exact match but two table2 rows, say in your example 1 apr 2009 - 30 jun 2009 **and** 1 apr 2011 - 30 jun 2011, and if there is a tie between two non-matching ranges. The rules to find the 'nearest' are just vague. Do you only ever look at *earlier* ranges from table2, or can you look at *later* ones too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
with table1 as (select 1 usr, to_date('01/01/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('31/03/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date, 'abc' parameter from dual union all
                select 1 usr, to_date('01/04/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('30/06/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date, 'abc' parameter from dual union all
                select 1 usr, to_date('01/01/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('31/03/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date, 'xyz' parameter from dual union all
                select 1 usr, to_date('01/04/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('30/06/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date, 'xyz' parameter from dual union all
                select 1 usr, to_date('01/01/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('31/03/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date, 'qqq' parameter from dual union all
                select 1 usr, to_date('01/04/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('30/06/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date, 'qqq' parameter from dual),
     table2 as (select 1 usr, to_date('01/01/2009', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('31/03/2009', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date, 'abc' parameter, 100 value from dual union all
                select 1 usr, to_date('01/04/2009', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('30/06/2009', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date, 'abc' parameter, 200 value from dual union all
                select 1 usr, to_date('01/01/2009', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('31/03/2009', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date, 'xyz' parameter, 300 value from dual union all
                select 1 usr, to_date('01/04/2009', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('30/06/2009', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date, 'xyz' parameter, 400 value from dual union all
                select 1 usr, to_date('01/01/2009', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('31/03/2009', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date, 'qqq' parameter, 500 value from dual union all
                select 1 usr, to_date('01/04/2009', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('30/06/2009', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date, 'qqq' parameter, 600 value from dual)
-- end of mimicking your tables; see SQL below:
select usr,
       start_date,
       end_date,
       parameter,
       latest_value,
       diff_days
from   (select usr,
               start_date,
               end_date,
               parameter,
               last_value(value ignore nulls) over (partition by usr, parameter order by start_date) latest_value,
               start_date - last_value(case when value is not null then start_date end ignore nulls) over (partition by usr, parameter order by start_date) diff_days
        from   (select usr,
                       start_date,
                       end_date,
                       parameter,
                       cast(null as number) value
                from   table1
                union all
                select usr,
                       start_date,
                       end_date,
                       parameter,
                       value
                from   table2))
where diff_days > 0;

       USR START_DATE  END_DATE    PARAMETER LATEST_VALUE  DIFF_DAYS
---------- ----------- ----------- --------- ------------ ----------
         1 01 jan 2010 31 mar 2010 abc                200        275
         1 01 apr 2010 30 jun 2010 abc                200        365
         1 01 jan 2010 31 mar 2010 qqq                600        275
         1 01 apr 2010 30 jun 2010 qqq                600        365
         1 01 jan 2010 31 mar 2010 xyz                400        275
         1 01 apr 2010 30 jun 2010 xyz                400        365
```

This uses the analytic function `last_value()` to find the latest non-null value for the value and its corresponding end_date, and then does the necessary subtraction to get the difference between the later periods' and the latest available period's start dates.

N.B. This assumes that there aren't overlapping periods across both tables.